# How can I search GitHub "Used by" repositories?

Tags: github

I am trying to find more examples of how a specific package is used (in this case [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python)) beyond the examples/README in the package.

In GitHub there is a "Used by" button that lists all the repositories using the package:
[image: 1300 repositories I'd like to search]

I would like to do a code search limited to these packages. For example, search for the word "scale" to see where others may have used ffmpeg-python to do a "scale" operation.

Any suggestions?

Thanks